# Load css dynamically in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I'm creating a content management system where a user can select a css file from their server and the application will parse and store the css.  The application will need to be able to parse the css classes out, record them, and store the css content to be dynamically added to another page where a user can select the different css classes from a drop down.  So does anyone know of a way to add css content to a page dynamically, for example from a database?  I've found a few projects for parsing the css, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/CSSParser.aspx) .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I originally posted this on Zruty's answer, but it applies to this question in general - You'll want to be careful how you chunk up your CSS. You probably don't want to create a CSS file for every page on your site. You should make use of client-side caching, so the user doesn't have to make an extra request every time they hit a page for the first time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good approach for a WebForms-only project is to link to an `.ashx` handler in your page instead of a static CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DynamicStyles.ashx" />
```

Then create the handler (add a 'Generic Handler' item from Visual Studio) and within it you can load the CSS from a database or wherever. Just make sure you set the content type correctly in the handler, so that browsers recognise the response as a valid stylesheet:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
```

Answer (score 10):

Make a controller which serves the CSS content:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Action("GetCss", "Serve", new {id="filename"})" />
```

Controller code:

```
public class ServeController: Controller
{
    public ContentResult GetCss(string id)
    {
        string cssBody = GetCssBodyFromDatabase(id);
        return Content(cssBody, "text/css");
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work, I believe. But you'll want to be careful how you chunk up your CSS. You probably don't want to create a CSS file for every page on your site. You should make use of client-side caching, so the user doesn't have to make an extra request every time they hit a page for the first time.

Comment: That looks like great way to do it asp.net mvc, but the project is only asp.net.

Comment: Oops, I think I worked too much yesterday evening, and I was seeing MVC everywhere. The ASP.NET version will be @minimalis' solution.

Answer (score 6):

I think NullReference gave you a MVC solution because you tagged your post "mvc". If you're using ASP.NET Web forms, you can use the same technique used when generating CSS-links on-the-fly on user-controls. On the page's Page_Init event, do something like the following (in the example below, I'm linking to jquery-ui-CSS):

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink jqueryUICSS;
     jqueryUICSS = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink();
     jqueryUICSS.Href = "styles/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css");
     jqueryUICSS.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
     jqueryUICSS.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
     Page.Header.Controls.Add(jqueryUICSS);
}
```

If you want actual  elements to be rendered on the header, then use *HtmlGeneric* control instead of *HtmlLink* in my example above. It's still the same technique--on Page_Init, add to the Page.Header.Controls collection:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl mystyles;
        mystyles = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl();
        mystyles.TagName = "style";
        string sampleCSS = "body { color: Black; } h1 {font-weight: bold;}";
        mystyles.InnerText = sampleCSS;
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(mystyles);
    }
```

Comment: Well I didn't know who tagged it with MVC. The important thing is that the MVC tag has been removed. :)