# Overriding css Style on aspx page with master page

Tags: css, asp.net, styles, overriding

I have a aspx web page using a master page.
There is a style.css sheet which is a global style.
How can I override the style for all the content in the aspx page, but not alter anything else?

so for example something like this in the aspx page

```
<asp:Content overridestyle = true>
...
</asp:Content>
```

EDIT

I found something that sort of sort of works, but it removes the style for the entire page, including the content on the masterpage. Is there anyway to do this solution but only for the content in the contentplaceholder?

```
new protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Theme = "";
}
```

Comment: add all the styles under <style> tag in this page. so that it will apply only on this page.

Answer (score 3):

Add the Content place holder in the master page like this under  section

```
<head runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

in your aspx page,

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <link href="*****style sheet path****" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I get two errors with this. First I get header is not found in masterpage file. So I changed it to ContentPlaceHolder1. Also I get link is not allowed inside a div error.

Comment: Yes, it my typing mistake. I edited the answer. regarding " link is not allowed inside a div error." is just a warning. You can still run the code.

Comment: this didn't seem to work. Is there anyway to just not use any style for any of the elements in the asp:content? I tried to just set the link to a empty css style I made but this didn't do it.

Comment: this link help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984718/load-css-dynamically-in-asp-net

Comment: I also tried to do StylesheetTheme="" Theme="" %> but this also didn't work