# Where should I store UI-related stuff?

Tags: html, css, database

Suppose, I have in a db a list of addresses which I want to show on a html page. There're, say, 5 of them and they're rarely changed, approximately once in a few month. However, they might be changed, added or deleted. I want to display each of them with a specific css style. Where should I store these css styles for each of them? In a db? But is it a good idea, though? I think UI-related stuff shouldn't be stored in a db. So then where should I it? Or should I hard-code it on an html page or in css file? It's not a good idea either to hard-code stuff.

Comment: If it is your requirement to keep the styles then just store it in DB. Databases are designed for storing data. Your info is data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when you use this style, on a new window from the selected address? if that is the case i would store the file where the css files is stored and create a generic handler to change the css file according to the selected address. [this is a good example](http://www.velocity-it.com/css-generic-handler-k2-smartforms/)

if you just want to change the style of the control or the address section then just store it in the database table. would do any harm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984718/load-css-dynamically-in-asp-net this is also a good example of the Generic handler.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the **MVC pattern**? Your application should be divided into 3 **separate** layers - **DB** communicating with **Business layer** (business application) which communicates with **UI** (UI application), it means that UI doesn't even see DB layer.

Also you probably don't quite understand **hardcode** meaning. Defining a CSS classes in CSS files is nothing wrong I suppose.